# Who is the -bash executing user on my server?

Tags: linux, bash, webserver

On one of my servers I noticed there where 2 active users. Who is that second user?

```
USER     TTY      FROM              LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
root     tty1                      10Feb15 127days  0.60s  0.58s -bash
root     pts/0    d54c40000.access 13:40    0.00s  0.19s  0.00s w
```

Obviously I'm user root on `pts/0` executing the `w` command.

But who/what is the `-bash` executing root user?

The `ps -fttty1` command gives me:

```
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root      1307     1  0 Feb10 tty1     00:00:00 /bin/login --     
root      2183  1307  0 Feb10 tty1     00:00:00 -bash
```

Answer (score 2):

I hope your servers **console** is not generally accessible, because root has been being logged in there for over 4 months. If your system is running some graphical login, this might be hidden and you have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to get at that console.

You should consider setting `TMOUT`, so that the root user automatically logs out. E.g. in your `/root/.profile`, or `/etc/profile` (to enforce a system wide auto-logout policy on inactivity):

```
TMOUT=600
```

for 10 minutes (the value is in seconds of inactivity).

Comment: Consider using `readonly TMOUT=600` to mark the variable as read-only and thus prevent defeating its setting.

Comment: Thanks Anthon,

I've added the timeout and restarted the server. Opened 2 connections and I'm waiting for the timeout.

Comment: @JRFerguson That makes sense especialy if you put it in /etc/profile for other users.

Comment: @JRFerguson added 'readonly TMOUT' and it worked fine... Thanks

Comment: `TMOUT` is dangerous, especially for root. I strongly recommend not to set it. It is dangerous because when you're repairing a broken system, keeping a root shell open may be important for continuity of service. When you're doing something that might break your ability to log in, keeping a root shell is important and a timeout must not get in the way. Making `TMOUT` read-only is even worse because it serves absolutely no security purpose (except for a restricted user). @Cleveridge

Comment: When you know you don't need it you just unset it on an individual basis